# Perform Text analysis on Incoming messages

Tags: android, message

I am creating an android application which will detect person mood through text messages, it will search for emo's and keywords that depict emotions, I have done else part, but now I am coming to messages, 
I have made a condition that my application will check person mood after 10 messages are sent and search keywords and set his/her mood.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body"}, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String smsBody = cur.getString(5);
                Log.v("body", smsBody);

                if (smsBody.contains(":(")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "found sad smiley in ur texts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"didnt found what u are looking for",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Right now my code is reading messages and also finds a keyword, but I want help in 2 things:

1. How to get latest messages.
2. Applying custom dictionary on messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following for reading inbox

```
  Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

int j = 0;
  Cursor c =this.getContentResoulver().query(message, null, null, null, null);

  int totalSMS = c.getCount();
if(totalSms >10)
j = 10;
else
j= totalSms;

 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j;i++) {
    String messageBody = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex   ("body"));
 c.moveToNext();
       }
}
```

To split a string  use following and search key words

```
String[] splitted_message = stringObject.split("");
```

and this array contains the words you can check with your keywords

Dont forget to add permission

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: i got your answer sir , just one more thing , in splitted_message , instead of stringobject , i have to use the string which contains the messages?
#thanks